# In Python, how can I use a concrete method of an abstract class in the inherited class?

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class, concrete-inheritance

So I have an abstract class which has one non-abstract (concrete) method:

```
class abstract_class(ABC):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0

    def new_method(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b  = 1
```

Now, I have another abstract class, which inherits from the `abstract_class`:

```
class inherited_class (ABC, abstract_class):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.c = 0

    def new_method(self):
    #to_do
```

Here is my question: both "`new_method`" methods are concrete. I want the second `new_method` to do everything the super class's `new_method` does, and in addition to that, does also this:
`self.c = 1`

What is the best way to achieve that?

I tried this:

```
    def new_method(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b  = 1
        self.c = 1
```

But I doubt if it's the best idea.

Comment: Just like how you called the parent class' `__init__`: Call the parent class' `super().new_method()`, followed by your `inherited_class` specific code?